# ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I upgraded my OS kali linux to the new version (Debian 4.19.28-2 kali) and when I rebooted, the wifi didn't work properly here is my  `rfkill` output

```
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Can anyone help me with the firmware? this is the ouput for `dmesg:`

```
 16.405392] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
[   16.405549] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input9
[   16.728375] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   16.981864] rtl8188ee 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[   17.009892] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   17.267994] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP TrueVision HD (05c8:038f)
[   17.286787] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   17.286794] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   17.286798] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   17.286979] input: HP TrueVision HD: HP TrueVision as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input14
[   17.287196] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   17.287198] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   29.018475] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   29.085524] r8169 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw
[   29.085884] Generic PHY r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
[   29.191648] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   29.201356] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   29.607278] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   30.021033] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   30.649791] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   42.081428] fuse init (API version 7.27)
[   86.992720] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  344.550286] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  472.605499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  472.640519] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode
[  474.457356] device wlan0 left promiscuous mode
[  535.094762] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  535.159932] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  659.127166] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  963.901965] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  963.901990] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  965.041456] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[  970.419667] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  989.830961] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1342.847925] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1658.886761] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1974.825465] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```